# CUDA // Building Blender Vs pre-Built binaries?

Tags: modeling, python, rendering, animation, mesh

Please answer me this. Provided that I have installed and working CUDA (CUDA 8.0 in my case), is there a difference between building Blender from source with CUDA option enabled Vs. using pre-built binaries from Blender web site?

Answer (score 0):

[Building Blender with CUDA support](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/CUDA) currently requires the CUDA Toolkit 10.1. If you want to create your own build with CUDA support, you will have to install the required dependencies. If you have all the dependencies installed, correct build configurations and create a release build (`make release`), then it should have the same features as the official release.